# Auto-layout making the same width for each element

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I am using auto-layout for my screen but despite I set the same width, same hugging priority and compression resistance(for all the textfield). I am having many warnings to ask me to set them differently but it looks different from what I want.

What I want:

- 1st row: The X seems to be hidden a part from the edges
- 2nd row: The textfields to
  be the same width and the dash can be shrink if space is running
  out(but visible).

[image]

Warnings:
[image]

Comment: Let me tell you that you should not use auto layout for this situation, that is very poor ui choice to create multiple input fields. instead have just one and limit that fields input and insert `-` in between letter/number groups via code where neccessary.

Comment: Thank you @luk2302 is there any articles to object multiple text fields in a row? I'm might have little power only on the designs as this has already approved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just have the constraints a little bit off. This is how they should look like:

1. Add a leading constraint from the first textField to the superview
2. Add horizontal constraints between the textFields (from the first one to the second and so on)
3. Add trailing constraint from the last one to the superview
4. Select all 3 textFields and add an equal width constraint to them

[image]

This should work, so you can achieve what you need. Let me know if you need more help